# How to make APIs for ios applications using django

Tags: python, ios, django, web-services, web

i am trying to make iOS application that communicate with server that has django framework installed on it , so i am asked about how can i make APIs using django to handel it with my App, like using using GET or POST methods , thanks in advance .

Comment: http://pydanny.com/choosing-an-api-framework-for-django.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at here: http://django-rest-framework.org/

This framework sits on top of django and gives you the abilty to use the power of RESTFULL Services. Than you can use GET/PUT and POST.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of REST packages for django/python check [djangopackages.com](http://djangopackages.com)

I'd recommend you to have a look at [tastypie](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)